# Install GF119M [Quadro NVS 4200M] (rev a1) drivers correctly

Tags: nvidia

I have a hybrid laptop Lenovo T420. I have disabled Optimus in BIOS and I'm only using discrete graphic (Nvidia) now. My Nvidia GFX worked before I upgraded to Ubuntu 13.04, but now the driver wont load.

I tried reinstalling the 'nvidia-current' driver with:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current nvidia-settings
```

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF119M [Quadro NVS 4200M] (rev a1)

$ uname -a
Linux laptop 3.8.0-21-generic #32-Ubuntu SMP Tue May 14 22:16:46 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ lsmod | grep -i nvidia 
$
```

Any clue on how to move on with this?

Comment: Does Unity still load or are you dropped in a commandline?

Comment: No Unity bar does not load. I boot op and come into the desktop.

Answer (score 1):

try a newer version of the driver, i not sure about 304-version as in current does support your video-card.

`sudo apt-get install nvidia-310 nvidia-settings-310`

or try latest 313

`sudo apt-get install nvidia-313-updates nvidia-settings-313-updates`

which both should be in the 13.04 repositories.

or use stable mein drivers from x-updates ppa:

`sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates`
`sudo apt-get update`

and install latest drivers from this ppa